# Null field treatment on PHP

Tags: php

I have a table named `hr events` where, in one field, it outputs when a certain employee went on maternity leave;

On the `return_date` field, it displays the date when the employee got back from the maternity leave.

If the employee has not come back yet, we set a default value, as seen on `CREATE` statement below: `CREATE (return_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',)`;

There is one last field on this report where it is supposed to show the employee's final return date to her activities: `(c.return_date ,'%d/%m/%Y') AS c_return_date`. As an SQL beginner, i'm struggling with this: whenever we have a `(default 0000-00-00)` value, `c.return_date` brings some sort of aleatory date, like: e.g 12/01/1999 , tho' it's a NULL field.

I've been trying to treat this with `ISNULL(c.return_date, '')` or `ISNULL(c.return_date, 0)` but it just doesn't work. In the above scenario, this last field should be blank or anything but this '12/01/1999'.

As for PHP, and that's why I'm editing this topic, I think there could be a way out of this by addressing this issue inside the php script:

```
<?php
    $retorno = (!empty($row['c_return_date'])) ? $row['c_return_date'] : $row['a_return_date'];
    $data = explode('-', $retorno);
    echo date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $data[1], $data[2] + 1, $data[0]));
?>
```

I'm currently trying to figure out (actually, more figuring out how does this script works) how to validate this script to, in case of a return date like `0000-00-00` (which means the employee has not come back yet to her activities), not display these sort of output like 12/01/1999.

Comment: Why would the return date be non-`NULL`?  That would seem like the right way to represent an employee who has not returned.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, it makes no sense at all. Thas why i've edited yhis topic. I feel like the answer might be in the php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, it was a php script issue.

```
<?php
                         $retorno = (!empty($row['c_return_date'])) ? $row['c_return_date'] : $row['a_return_date'];
                         $data = explode('-', $retorn);
                         echo date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1], $date[2] + 1, $date[0]));
                         ?>
```

I just needed to put a contitional statement on the script above, to prevent `c_return_date`from displaying anything in case `a_return_date` is 0000-00-00. Take a look at the if / else clauses:

```
<?php
                          if ($row['a_return_date'] != "0000-00-00"){
                            $return = (!empty($row['c_return_date'])) ? $row['c_return_date'] : $row['a_return_date'];
                            $data = explode('-', $return);
                             echo date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1], $date[2] + 1, $date[0]));
                             } else $row['a_return_date_br'] = "-";
                             ?>
```

Thank you all. Hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: If (and only if) you're not using dates in an array later in your script, a way to echo the date is using date ('Y-m-d",  strtotime($retorno)) ; that way you avoid an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a random date. It's just a date represented by `0000-00-00` in MySQL.

I would use NULL:

```
create table hr_events (return_date date default null);
```

That way you could query list this:

```
select * from hr_events where return_date is null;
```

To get all `hr_events` rows where `return_date` has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend allowing your date field to be nullable:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (return_date DATE, ...)
```

Then, allow `null` to semantically mean that the employee has not yet returned from maternity leave.  You may use `COALESCE` to replace that `null` value with some default date:

```
SELECT COALESCE(return_date, '1999-12-01') AS return_date
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Yeah , that would be the perfect scenario. But, in this project, i'm not allowed to perfom any changes in the database structure.